# Very first HTTP request for a particluar REST API takes a lot of time but subsequent requests are quick

Tags: rest, api, http

I'm requesting a REST API through a HTTP Client from my machine (fiddler and C# app) and very first time, it takes around 30 seconds to get a response but it's very quick (around 250 ms) for subsequent requests to the same API.

- REST API has been hosted on a different environment
- Using fiddler and a C# app as client for the requests and both results in         same way
- The same REST API if requested from a different machine (in same domain, not API hosted one) is not having problem and very quick. So it's my machine only.
- However there is no issue when requesting the REST API from any browser(IE, Chrome, Firefox) and REST Console.
- I tried toggling 'Reuse server connections' (ON by default) option in fiddler and found that disabling that is making all requests slower (around 30 secs)
- No impact of 'Reuse client Connections' option in fiddler

Could you please suggest what is the problem here as to why requests are taking so much time for a response and how can it be solved.